# how to build the payload from an interface with Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

Hello there i have the follow interface:

```
export interface SearchFilter{
  assetTypeIds?: ("Portfolios"| "Indexes" | "Reports")[];
}
```

When i want to build the json:

```
const payload: SearchFilter = {
  assetTypeIds: "Portfolios"
}
```

or

```
 const payload: SearchFilter = {
  assetTypeIds: ["Portfolios"]
}
```

I have the follow error:

[image: any idea ?]

Any idea ? thanks.

Comment: What typescript version are you using?

Comment: I think your second snippet is valid, but where as in first one, `assetTypeIds` must be an array type

Comment: happens that am trying to add a Unknown value and i have the error but in the interface i specified the Unknown Value... this maybe because  Unknown shouldn't be specified as string ?

Answer (score 1):

this is just a logic error you can try this code:

```
type TorArrayT<T> = T | T[]

export interface SearchFilter{
  assetTypeIds?: TorArrayT<"Portfolios"| "Indexes" | "Reports">
}
```

Comment: in your code you are specifying `assetTypeIds` could be `void` could be array containing values